# Difference between countable unions and union of any two arbitrary sets in the context of sigma fields.

Tags: measure-theory

One of the criteria for a collection of events to be a sigma field is that it should be closed under all "countable unions" as the textbook says. However almost all the places i referred have countable unions defined on a sequence of sets that belong to the collection. So what exactly is the criteria saying ? That if any two sets belong to the collection their unions must also belong, or that the unions of all possible sequences that can be formed from the collection must also be in the collection ?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Apart from the argument with the empty set, *finite* is also *countable*.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy But sequences may repeat elements, so I don't think you need to mention the empty set. In any case you will have to repeat the empty set, so what's the advantage of $A\cup B\cup\emptyset\cup\emptyset\cup\emptyset\cup\cdots$ over $A\cup B\cup A\cup B\cup A\cup\cdots$?

Answer (score 2):

That if $\{S_i\}_{i\in I}$ is a collection of sets from $\mathcal A$ (the to-be sigma algebra) and $I$ is a countable set (i.e., is either finite or infinite of cardinality $\aleph_0$), then $\bigcup_{i\in I}S_i\in \mathcal A$. This is equivalent to saying that the union of any sequence of sets from $\mathcal A$ is in $\mathcal A$.

Comment: but we can form arbitrarily many sequences by changing the order of the elements chosen from A so should it still hold true for all of them ?

Comment: @Examination12345 Who cares? $\bigcup_{i\in I}S_i=\{x\,:\, \exists i\in I, x\in S_i\}$, so "order" doesn't matter.

Comment: @Gae.S. pardon me if this sounds dumb but for an index i in I, isn't it our choice to assign an arbitrary element S to it ? Therefore if the collection is {S1, S2, S3, ... Si} and it indeed is closed under countable unions then that implies S1 U S2 is an element, S1 U S2 U S3 is an element and so on. But what about two elements say S1 and S9. The union of just S1 and S9 is not generated by the above means of countable union, or is it ? So how is it possible to sat S1 U S9 is also an element of the collection ?